# Built in webcam not working in chrome (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, webcam

I have an external webcam which works fine.

When unplugged, the built in webcam doesn't work in chrome: hangouts, gotomeeting, etc. It is recognized but it displays a black screen.

**It does work in cheese and skype.**

Thanks!